# How to add scrollable pdf file on xarigan slide

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I learned how to insert a certain page of pdf file on my xaringan slide using the following code:

````
```
{r}
magick::image_read_pdf("document.pdf", pages = 1)
```
````

The problem is I still cannot see the item on the page because it is located in down below. So I wonder if there's any function like `leaflet` so that I may be able to scroll the pdf document down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try embed a pdf file using `embed` html tag, like this,

````
---
title: "Adding scrollable pdf file in xaringan"
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
#embeded_pdf {
 width: 100%; 
 height: 70%;
}

```

## Adding a pdf file

<embed src="lorem_ipsum.pdf" type="application/pdf" id="embeded_pdf">
````

---

[image: embeded_pdf_in_xaringan]

---

**Note that,**

- **Open the output html file (xaringan slide) in your browser, Rstudio does not show the embedded files in xaringan slides; but in browser, it works fine.**
- **And in `src` option of `embed` tag, provide the file path of the pdf file that you want to embed.**

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. It does just the same as my original code does. I cannot still see the margins and scroll bars on the right. did I miss something here?

Comment: @Joe, Can you see the scrollbars in my included image? My answer is not same as your code, since `embed` directly adding the pdf file while `image_read_pdf` adding the image file obtained from the pdf file. Did you try exactly as shown in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I copied the exactly the same way

Comment: can you try my code in a new rmarkdown file and whats the browser you are using? (The above answer works perfectly in google chrome)

Comment: mine is safari, that may be the reason. let me try with chrome

Comment: yeah it works perfect with chrome. thanks! still wondering why not working with safari. any thought?